# C extensions error while importing pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I know there are quite a lot of questions related to this but no one has the answer for me as they are all using Anaconda or Unix environment.

I installed Python 3.7.1 for Windows 7, as well as pandas 0.23.4 with `pip`. So I do no more than `import pandas as pd` (both through jupyter and console) and it spits out this

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
c:\users\4217109\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\__init__.py in <module>
     25 try:
---> 26     from pandas._libs import (hashtable as _hashtable,
     27                              lib as _lib,

c:\users\4217109\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\_libs\__init__.py in <module>
      3 
----> 4 from .tslib import iNaT, NaT, Timestamp, Timedelta, OutOfBoundsDatetime
      5 

ImportError: cannot import name 'iNaT' from 'pandas._libs.tslib' (unknown location)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-3d5cd439516e> in <module>
----> 1 import pandas as pd
      2 from datetime import date, datetime
      3 import calendar

c:\users\4217109\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\__init__.py in <module>
     33                       "pandas from the source directory, you may need to run "
     34                       "'python setup.py build_ext --inplace --force' to build "
---> 35                       "the C extensions first.".format(module))
     36 
     37 from datetime import datetime

ImportError: C extension: 'iNaT' from 'pandas._libs.tslib' (unknown location) not built. If you want to import pandas from the source directory, you may need to run 'python setup.py build_ext --inplace --force' to build the C extensions first.
```

Who can tell me how to overcome this? Probably the error message suggestion sounds obvious but I just don't understand it so I'll appreciate if someone explains it step by step.

Comment: Can you show which line of code is popping-up this error?

Comment: did you try `python setup.py build_ext --inplace --force`? open a cmd, cd to your directory and run that line

Comment: @ParvBanks line number 1 of 1.

Comment: @StevenG what directory? User home directory? Python's directory? my script directory? pandas directory?

Comment: to your pandas directory in site-packages

Comment: For Windows download the [32-bit/64-bit binary version](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pandas) than use pip to install the wheel.

Comment: `python: can't open file 'setup.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory`. Indeed, there is no setup.py file in C:\Users\4217109\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\Lib\site-packages\pandas

Comment: download the git https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas and then unzip, and from that folder run the command

Comment: Parfait's suggestion ends with the same result. Steven's says ImportError: cannot import name 'MappingProxyType' from 'types'.

Comment: Finally I installed all over again but with miniconda this time, as I believe that pure Python installation of pandas lacks of compiled libraries and I wasn't able to compile them.

Answer (score 0):

Followed the setup.com procedure suggested on the pandas cloned from github.
This required a `pip --update` of Cython. (no setup.com in the site_packages/pandas).
Then I uninstall and reinstalled pandas.
Happy to report that fixed the problem!